# sharepoint ssrs report get query strings

Tags: sharepoint, reporting-services

I have a reporting service in Sharepoint integrated mode. How could I get report parameters via query strings? please explain it with some examples!

Answer (score 0):

Sending parameters to a report with values from a querystring can be done by prefixing the parameter with rp:

```
?rp:parameter=parameterValue
```

It is also possible to f.ex add a hidden filter webpart to your page that reads the querystring and sends the value to the report webpart.

For the future: Please let us know what you have tried and some more information about your problem instead of just asking the question and expecting to get a full answer.

Comment: For now not future, I have a ssrs report and want to render it in sharepoint content. my question is how could I send report parameter via querystring??? I thanked you if answer my question instead of change the question and explain it in your way to use filter webpart!

Comment: Updated my answer. Since we really don't know anything about your problem/system/reports it's not the easiest task to actually understand what you are after, but try prefixing your parameters in the URL with "rp:". Hopefully that will work, if not we need more info in order to help you.